# set color in shortcode php file for output

Tags: php, colors, shortcode

I can set color for an echo'' but i dont know how to do it same thing for "befor_text" and "after_text".

Can anybody teach me about that ? thank you...

```
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'user_id'    => 'current',
            'title'      => '',
            'befor_text'  => '',
            'title_el'   => 'h1',
            'balance_el' => 'div',
            'wrapper'    => 1,
            'formatted'  => 1,
            'after_text' => '',
            'type'       => MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY

        ), $atts ) );

        $output = '';

        // Not logged in
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $user_id == 'current' )
            return $content;

        // Get user ID
        $user_id = mycred_get_user_id( $user_id );

        // Make sure we have a valid point type
        if ( ! mycred_point_type_exists( $type ) )
            $type = MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY;

        // Get the users myCRED account object
        $account = mycred_get_account( $user_id );
        if ( $account === false ) return;

        // Check for exclusion
        if ( empty( $account->balance ) || ! array_key_exists( $type, $account->balance ) ) return;

        $balance = $account->balance[ $type ];

        if ( $wrapper )
            $output .= '<div class="mycred-my-balance-wrapper">';

        // Title
        if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
            if ( ! empty( $title_el ) )
                $output .= '<' . $title_el . '>';

            $output .= $title;

            if ( ! empty( $title_el ) )
                $output .= '</' . $title_el . '>';
        }

        //Text befor balance output
        if ( ! empty( $befor_text ) ){
            $output .= $befor_text;
        }


        // Balance
        if ( ! empty( $balance_el ) )
            $output .= '<' . $balance_el . '>';

        if ( $formatted )
            $output .= $balance->type->format( $balance->current );
        else
            $output .= $balance->type->number( $balance->current );

        if ( ! empty( $balance_el ) )
            $output .= '</' . $balance_el . '>';

        if ( $wrapper )
            $output .= '</div>';

        //Text after balance output
        if ( ! empty( $after_text ) ){
            $output .= $after_text;
        }
        return $output;

    }
endif;
add_shortcode( 'mycred_my_balance', 'mycred_render_shortcode_my_balance' );

?>
```

Comment: you can just append the html code with inline styling for the colors to the `$befor_text` and `$after_text` variables.. it will then be rendered when it is displayed.

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. As it stands now, it is quite hard to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PatrickQ , I think he would like to change the color for the text of the specified variables.. well that's what I got form his question at least

Comment: i try to creat a shortcode which you can see how much Credits you have like "(befor_text) My Balance:" "Amount from Balance(balance)" "(after_text) Credits" as example 'My Balance: 200 Credits ' and i want to set color for 'My Balance' and 'Credits'.

How can i set color in HTML for variables Patrick Q ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just wrap each of those pieces of text in a `span` and give a different class to each.  Then just add some CSS to define the colors you want.

```
...

//Text befor balance output
if ( ! empty( $befor_text ) ){
    $output .= "<span class='before_text'>".$befor_text."</span>";
}

...

//Text after balance output
if ( ! empty( $after_text ) ){
    $output .= "<span class='after_text'>".$after_text."</span>";
}
```

CSS

```
.before_span {
    color: red;
}

.after_span {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: oooooo so eaaaasyyy :) YOU ARE THE BEST MAN thank you

Comment: @EnEs If this solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted so that people know. Also, accepting answers will make it more likely that people provide answers for your questions in the future.